# using the same bunch of attributes in many classes

Tags: ruby

Please help me out.

I need to use the same bunch of attributes in many classes. I would suggest to create module with predefined attributes and extend this module in every class

```
module Basic
 @a=10
end

class Use
 extend Basic
 def self.sh
  @a
 end
end

puts Use.sh
```

but the output is empty. It seems like I missed something.

Maybe there is a better way to do that?

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [all about the `self`](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/15/metaprogramming-in-ruby-its-all-about-the-self/):

```
module Basic
  @a=10
end
```

has `self` evaluating to Basic. You want it to evaluate to `Use` when the latter is extended:

```
module Basic
  # self = Basic, but methods defined for instances
  class << self
    # self = Basic's eigenclass
    def extended(base)
      base.class_eval do
        # self = base due to class_eval
        @a=10
      end
    end
  end
end

class Use
  # self = Use, but methods defined for instances
  extend Basic # base = Use in the above
  class << self
    # self = Use's eigenclass
    def sh
      @a
    end
  end
end

Use.sh # 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, just one more question, I can't figure out what  `extended(base)` actually means. Can give me a link? Thanks!

Comment: [extended()](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000459) is a bit like [included()](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000458): it's a module method which kicks in when you use `extend Basic` (it then calls `Basic.extend(Use)`). `included()` kicks in when you use `include Basic`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is the Flyweight design pattern. While some view this as rarely used in ruby ( http://designpatternsinruby.com/section02/flyweight.html ), others provide an implementation ( http://www.scribd.com/doc/396559/gof-patterns-in-ruby page 14 )

Personally, what I would do is to put all these attributes into a yaml file, and parse them either into a global variable:

ATTRIBUTES = YAML.load_file(File.expand_path('attributes.yml', File.dirname(**FILE**))

or a class method (with caching here, assuming you won't change the yml file while the app is running and need the new values). I'd suggest using `ActiveSupport::Concern` here as it's easier to read than the traditional way of mixing in class methods:

```
module Basic
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def attributes_file
      File.expand_path('attributes.yml', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    def attributes
      @attributes ||= YAML.load_file(attributes_file)
      @attributes
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    # define any here that you need, like:
    def attributes
      self.class.attributes
    end
  end 
end
```

You can define methods for each of the attributes, or rely on indexing into the attributes hash. You could also get fancy and define method_missing to check if an attribute exists with that name, so that you don't have to keep adding methods as you want to add more attributes to the shared configs.

Comment: If you're hoping to change the values, and have the updated values shared between classes, then a Singleton would probably be the best approach.